# Unity broken, can't install due to unmet dependencies

Tags: unity, dependencies

Error Message: 
unmet dependencies libunity-core-6.09-9 (=7.2.2+14.04.20140714-0ununtu1) but 7.2.4+14.04.20141217-0ubuntu1 is to be installed

Removed compiz as directed by one of the answers earlier and it broke unity.

I don't have frames around firefox or any other app I can load from my desktop and I can only load apps that are on my desktop.

I tried sudo apt-get install unity and get an unmet dependencies error.  The first time it listed about 12 or more items which i manually installed.

Now I only get this message.

---

I don't have unity back yet, but I was able to load Lubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-desktop and gnome.  So at least I can get around now.  However, gnome core has the same problem as unity.

I am still looking for an answer.

Thank you

Comment: Could you give the link to that answer?  Furthermore, have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa  (just run it from TTY1)

Answer (score 0):

run this commands

```
sudo apt-get clean    
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried the following: 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get -f install
(I just did the above )
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get intstall -f -y unity
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unbuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
and I don't remember how many others.

Comment: PKumar: add 4 spaces in front of commands lists (please [review  my edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/584662/revisions) )